# Octokit.net - Github Xamarin

Tags: .net, mobile, xamarin, octokit

i'm using Xamarin and now i need to use Octokit.Net - a library for cross-platform.
I'm cant find any useful document or example about this library to work on xamarin(mobile)
Any one can help please...
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to install the package through Xamarin Studio like any other NuGet package.

In terms of docs, here's a good [getting started](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.net/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md) guide, and there are some other docs [here](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.net/tree/master/docs) which I'm working on whenever I have some spare time.

Comment: Wow, i didn't see it carefully, tks bro